# Java method returning memory address

Tags: java

the following function returns a memory address instead of the actual Node its supposed to, any input?:

```
public Node getNode(){
    Node nextnode = new Node(this.title, this.disX, this.disY);
    return nextnode;
}
```

When called such as:

```
AcNode aNode = new AcNode("Test", 0.5, 0.6)
System.out.println("See next node" + aNode.getNode());
```

AcNode is a subclass of Node, using the same constructor as a super. Any help?

Comment: You should @Override toString() method.

Comment: See this: [How do I print my Java object without getting “SomeType@2f92e0f4”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you concatenate an object onto a String like you are doing there, the `toString` method will be called. By default the `toString` method will be called internally if you don't define a `toString` method, which will print a "memory address" pointing to the object. So you need to define a `toString` method in your `Node` class that returns the information you are looking for in that case.

Alternatively, you can call a getter instead of relying on the `toString` method:

```
aNode.getNode().getIdentifier()
```

or whatever your getter method is called (getIdentifier is just an example).

Comment: Could you give me an example of getIdentifier in my case? I'm struggling to understand what it means

Comment: `public String getIdentifier() { return title; }`

Comment: In details default toString() consist of class name, then @ and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code.